# Get substring according to occurrence, reg exp java

Tags: java, regex, string

Good day everyone! I wonder if anyone could help me out.

I have a string `-2.100 CM 1.000 CM 1.025 CM`

The problem is getting the values before `CM`, e.g. `-2.1`, `1.0`, `1.025`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\-*\\d*.\\d*) CM"); would give me -2.1, 

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" (\\-*\\d*.\\d*) CM"); 1.0
```

Can not get the third value ( Is there any way of getting the values according to their occurrences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string.

```
String str = "-2.100 CM 1.000 CM 1.025 CM";

String[] array = str.split("\\s+CM\\s*");
for (String s : array) {
    System.out.println(new Double(s));
}
```

output:

```
-2.1
1.0
1.025
```

---

You can try with Pattern as well using *Positive Lookahead*.

```
String str = "-2.100 CM 1.000 CM 1.025 CM";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+-]?\\d+\\.?\\d*(?= CM)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(new Double(m.group()));
}
```

output:

```
-2.1
1.0
1.025
```

Comment: This regex will match `1.000`. The OP only wants to match `1.0`.

Comment: Nope, because then it would only match `1.0` for `1.025` as well. The OP wants to match `1.025`.

Comment: @AmalMurali Now it will work using `new Double(m.group())` Thanks.

Comment: Like the first solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String input = "-2.100 CM 1.000 CM 1.025 CM";
String[] result = input.split("\\s*CM\\s*");
```